# Ubuntu 18.04, Inkscape 0.92: Cannot change icons

Tags: gnome, inkscape, icon-themes

I am using a global dark theme on Ubuntu 18.04 and it makes all the icons in Inkscape 0.92 hard to see.

I found an icons.svg with better icons and copied them to ~/.config/inkscape/icons but when I restart Inkscape nothing changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The output of `which inkscape` is `/usr/bin/inkscape`

Comment: How did you installed Inkscape - from APT or from Snap? Please add output of `which inkscape` to the question.

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem. It seems that the `icons.svg` files in `/usr/share/inkscape/icons` or `~/.config/inkscape/icons` get overwritten by the Gnome icon theme.

You can change the Gnome icon theme with the Gnome Tweaks tool (`gnome-tweaks`) and choose a icon set that doesn't change the Inkscape icons.

In my case the Gnome icons that affect Inkscape are in `/usr/share/icons/<theme-name>/22x22/actions`. Unlike the default icons each icon has it's own svg file, and they are not all bundled in a `icons.svg` file.